# Create directories from textfile

Tags: command-line

I have a text file named checklog.txt. I want to create directories from that names in the text file line by line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cat checklog.txt | xargs -L 1 mkdir
```

Worked  for me.

Comment: No need to using cat command, "xargs -L 1 mkdir < checklog.txt" can be use instead

Comment: If you directory names contain spaces, enclose them in quotes